# Easiest way to batch convert images to grayscale jpg

Tags: image, scripting, jpeg, grayscale, utility

Our web application needs jpg grayscale images to process them. We have applied conversion logic on server side for images, but it will be waste of resources to do it on server side as we will process thousands of pages per person(as of the nature of the application use).

Now what we want to do is encourage users to convert their images to jpg grayscale. For this purpose i am looking up the easy ways to convert commong types of images to grayscale jpg. I will write a guide for all common platform(windows, linux/ubuntu, mac) for non-technical users. But i am unable to find any easy way, like some simple scripts, or small multi-platform utility for the purpose.

So, if any one can suggest some good utilities for the purpose, preferably small size, maximum automated(like a script which will convert all iamges in the folder it resides to grayscale jpg). Because our goal is to make it easy for the users as much as possible. With as minimum additional download as possible.

And seeing lack of any such guide on internet, i will also post that guide on my blog.

Thankyou in advance for any help.

Comment: Thinking to use ImageMagick and give users scripts for windows/linux separately for batch conversion.

Comment: Sounds like you should modify your web application instead of making everyone else accommodate the limitation. If an app can read color jpegs, it's trivial to request that it decompresses them directly to grayscale.

Comment: @BitBank We had same thoughts, but thinking thoroughly we colcluded that its better that suers give us grayscale images, as i have mentioned we are working with large set of images(thousands to millions), and if we start converting each image to grayscale on server it will be waste of resources as our algorithms already are very heavy for image processing, it will add more delay in the process time of the images to produce desirable results.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I didn't say to convert the images to grayscale on your server. I said that whatever process you're using to process the images can request that color images are decompressed directly to grayscale (Y-channel only). For my own codec, this doubles the decode speed.

Comment: ohk, i got what you saying, but @BitBank as of my knowledge, we need to run some algorithm on rgb images to get greyscale image. Can you please guide me how can i avoid those calculations on whole image.

Comment: I suppose you are talking about (Method 5 – Single color channel) on this page, not the Method 4 –( Decomposition) http://www.tannerhelland.com/3643/grayscale-image-algorithm-vb6/ Please confirm. And also if this is a reliable method for automated tasks.

Comment: The YCbCr colorspace of JPEG images already has the "grayscale" information ready to use (the Y channel). There is no need for an algorithm to convert RGB to grayscale. Whatever code you're using to decode the JPEG images can just decode the Y channel directly.

Comment: alright, thankyou for your suggestion @BitBank, i think i will use the method mentioned in the above link, because requesting Y channel from rgb may cause it to convert rgb to YCbCr in background, and i am trying to avoid any extra processing. Because as of my knowledge, RGB and YCbCr conversion in one another needs an algorithm(which we had written in our image processing course), and we don't want this processing. Thankyou again for showing me the path.

Comment: And please do correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Adobe products can sometimes create RGB JPEG files, but the vast majority are stored in the YCbCr colorspace. Decoding a JPEG image usually involves converting the YCbCr to RGB. If you configure the decoder properly, there is no need to go YCbCr->RGB->grayscale. You can ask the decoder to go YCbCr->Y. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @BitBank i got it, we can extract Y channel form YCbCr, but we have to handle RGB too, it is also very poplar format and scanner do support it. I was asking about that. Its cent percent clear about YCbCr was just finalizing about RGB handling.